# Как перебрать элементы кортежа и добавить их в модель (таблицу базы данных)

Tags: python, django, list, словари, кортежи

У меня есть список с вложенными словарями и кортежами, мне необходимо добавить элементы в базу данных, я это делаю так (элемент кортежа добавляется с использованием индекса):

```
class Content(models.Model): 
    nmId = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    colors = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)

data=[{'sizes': [{'chrtID': 68964543, 'techSize': '50', 'skus': ['2003633919020', '2003754125620']}, {'chrtID': 68964544, 'techSize': '52', 'skus': ['2003633919037']}],
    'mediaFiles': ['1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg', '4.jpg', '5.jpg', '6.jpg', '7.jpg', '8.jpg'], 
    'colors': ['голубой', 'белый', 'зеленый', 'красный'], 
    'updateAt': '2023-05-07', 
    'vendorCode': 'П0015П0015Г', 
    'nmID': 31907549, 
    'imtID': 23856780, 
    'isProhibited': False, 
    'tags': []}]

for key1 in data:
        Content.objects.create(
        nmId = key1['nmID'],
        colors = key1['colors'][0],
        )
```

и это почти работает, в таблицу добавляется первый элемент кортежа, а если кортеж пуст, то возникает ошибка.
Как правильно перебрать элементы кортежа, чтобы добавить их в бд? (что то вроде этого):

```
for key1 in data:
    for key2 in data['colors']:    
        Content.objects.create(
        nmId = key1['nmID'],
        colors = key2['colors'],
        )
```

Comment: 1. Судя по вашему коду вы хотите сделать отдельный объект для каждого цвета, верно? Или у вас many-to-one поле? 2. Метод `create` у менеджера `objects` ваш собственный?

Хотелось бы увидеть и модель `Content` (хотя бы поля из вопроса), и метод `create`.

Comment: 1. да - для простоты понимания: каждому цвету отдельная строка в таблице, nmId - повторяется. 2. метод create - стандартный метод создания объектов в модели.?

Comment: 2. Строго говоря, нет. Это просто в документации говорится, что если вы хотите изменить инициализацию моделей, то это нельзя делать через `__init__`. Канонический способ создания объектов по одному - через обычную инициализацию `Content(nmId=1, colors='foo',) ` и использование `save`. Обновил ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В целом, довольно стандартный проход по словарю:

```
for item in data:
    item_nm_id = item.get('nmID', 0) # 0 - значение по умолчанию, если нет в словаре
    for color in item.get('colors', []): # опять же, чтобы не было KeyError
        new_content = Content(nmId=item_nm_id, colors=color,)
        new_content.save()
```

Если ожидается очень много объектов, стоит посмотреть на использование [bulk_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create)

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!